# One Elastic Beanstalk app can see my RDS but the other cant

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, rds

I have 2 Elastic Beanstalk applications (lets call them K1Web and K1WebAPI) running and a separated RDS instance.

K1Web can see my RDS (I added K1Web Group ID in my RDS inbound list).
I did this a week ago.

Today I created a second application (K1WebAPI) and added K1WebAPI Group ID to my RDS inbound list as well, but K1WebAPI doesn't seen to find the RDS instance.
My K1WebAPI application keep saying it can`t find my database.

Maybe I did something else when I configured K1Web a week ago and I don`t remeber, but I think all I did was editing RDS inbound list.

Does anyone have a clue? Am I missing something? Is there something to do with subnet? I am lost.

Here is my groups and my RDS inbound list. As you can see, I did add my instances groups to it.

thank you in advance!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rPWt.png)

Answer (score 1):

The [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rPWt.png) you showed us is of EC2 (Classic) security groups. That is not the place to configure RDS security groups. Instead you should navigate to the RDS service, select 'Security Groups' from the left nav, and authorize inbound connections to your DB there.

Comment: Thats what I get when I select "Security Groups" in RDS section:

"Your account does not support the EC2-Classic Platform in this region. DB Security Groups are only needed when the EC2-Classic Platform is supported. Instead, use VPC Security Groups to control access to your DB Instances. Go to the EC2 Console to view and manage your VPC Security Groups. For more information, see AWS Documentation on Supported Platforms and Using RDS in VPC."

Answer (score 0):

Today, when I woke up and tried again and my application could see my RDS instance.
As I said, I did nothing besides added it to rds's inbound list.
It seems like the replication is not that fast... I don't know, but it is working now. Thank you, guys!